# Trouble with shift and dereference operator

Tags: perl

I have a question regarding how the left and right sides of the `->` operator are evaluated. Consider the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.10';

$, = ': ';
$" = ', ';

my $sub = sub { "@_" };

sub u { shift->(@_) }
sub v { my $s = shift; $s->(@_) }

say 'u', u($sub, 'foo', 'bar');
say 'v', v($sub, 'foo', 'bar');
```

Output:

```
u: CODE(0x324718), foo, bar
v: foo, bar
```

I expect u and v to behave identically but they don't. I always assumed perl evaluated things left to right in these situations. Code like `shift->another_method(@_)` and even `shift->another_method(shift, 'stuff', @_)` is pretty common.

Why does this break if the first argument happens to be a code reference? Am I on undefined / undocumented territory here?

Comment: This is only a partial answer: although there's only one `->` operator documented, `->()`, `->[]`, `->{}` and `->method` are actually implemented as entirely different operators.

Comment: @RobEarl, My answer there says that the arguments are evaluated before the method call (which is a no-brainer), not before the LHS. Even if `->()` worked the same as method calls, that doesn't help here.

Comment: @RobEarl, Interestingly, the LHS of `->method(@args)` is evaluated before the args, so `shift->foo(@_)` does work as expected! (Probably cause that's a very tempting thing to do on a regular basis, so it's worth the extra up front stack usage.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operand evaluation order of `->()` is undocumented. It happens to evaluate the arguments before the LHS (lines 3-4 and 5 respectively below).

```
>perl -MO=Concise,u,-exec a.pl
main::u:
1  <;> nextstate(main 51 a.pl:11) v:%,*,&,x*,x&,x$,$,469762048
2  <0> pushmark s
3  <#> gv[*_] s
4  <1> rv2av[t2] lKM/3
5  <0> shift s*
6  <1> entersub[t3] KS/TARG,2
7  <1> leavesub[1 ref] K/REFC,1
a.pl syntax OK
```

Both using and modifying a variable in the same expression can be dangerous. It's best to avoid it unless you can explain the following:

```
>perl -E"$i=5; say $i,++$i,$i"
666
```

You could use

```
$_[0]->(@_[1..$#_])
```